# How to use the 'input' method to get a function argument (python)

Tags: python, function, return

So I have this code in python:

```
num = input("Choose your number?")
def distance_from_zero(num):
    if type(num) == int or type(num) == float:
        return abs(num)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

I'm trying to get the function argument (num) to be a number that the user put's in.

But whenever I run the code, I'll enter the argument, but it won't return anything, and the code ends.

How do I fix this problem? I'm not sure if its the positioning of the code, or something else.

Comment: You've only defined the function. You're not calling it.

Comment: Defining the function with a parameter named the same as `num` does not imply the parameter is *automagically* passed to the function.

Answer (score -2):

You need to **call** your function:

```
distance_from_zero(num)
```

**Update**:

```
def distance_from_zero(num):
     if type(num) == int or type(num) == float:
         return abs(num)
     else:
         return "Nope"
num = input()
distance_from_zero(num)
```

In python3 `input()` returns a string, if you are using that you need to convert it into **int**.

```
int(input())
```

Just an observation, this seems to be working function definition:

```
def fun(num = int(input())):
  print("num:",num)

fun()
```

Comment: You certainly can't define functions like that.